# Unsure about use of matrix_world

Tags: python, rendering, mesh, scripting, camera

### Some Context

I have a computer vision task where I have to generate some synthetic data from rendered images of a 3D model(liver). So to do that, I have first to generate a bounding box around that 3D model and create voxel or vertices/nodes centers every 7m and then to store the image coordinates in the rendered image of all the voxels which lie in the camera frame in a particular scene.
[image]

### My Implementation

The thing is that I am not sure how to implement this using blender's API so in order to get around that, I created a bounding box around the liver object and got the range of coordinates in all 3 dimensions and used `np.meshgrid()` from NumPy to create all the possible combinations of the points in that bounding box. My implementation is down below.

```
import bpy
x_max = -1000000 
y_max = -1000000 
z_max = -10000000
x_min = 1000000 
z_min = 1000000 
y_min = 10000000 
obj = bpy.data.objects['BoundingBox']
for v in obj.data.vertices:
    x = v.co[0] 
    y = v.co[1]
    z = v.co[2]
    x_max = max(x_max  ,x)
    x_min = min(x_min , x)
    y_max = max(y_max  ,y)
    y_min = min(y_min , y)
    z_max = max(z_max  ,z)
    z_min = min(z_min , z)
xdim = list(range(int(x_min) , int(x_max) , 7))
ydim =list(range(int(y_min) , int(y_max) , 7))
zdim =list(range(int(z_min) , int(z_max) , 7))
grid  = np.array(np.meshgrid(xdim , ydim , zdim)).T.reshape(3 , -1)
```

Now my for the second part  I have used `world_to_camera_view` from `bpy_extras` as follows.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['liver']
ix=[]
iy=[]
not_visible =[]
render_scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
render_size = (
    int(scene.render.resolution_x * render_scale),
    int(scene.render.resolution_y * render_scale),
)
for i in range(len(grid)):
    vert= Vector((grid[i][0] , grid[i][1]  , grid[i][2]))
    cords = world_to_camera_view(scene , cam , vert)
    if(0.0 <cords.x<1.0 and 0.0<cords.y<1.0 ):
        ix.append(cords.x*render_size[0])
        iy.append(cords.y*render_size[1])
    else:
        not_visible.append(f)
```

However, as I'm new to blender, I've seen some people use `cords = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam,obj.matrix_world @ vert)` instead, how of how I've done, which confuses me quite a lot and makes me unsure about the correctness of my implementation. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your liver is at (0, 0, 0) unit scale and zero rotation, then it has Identity matrix as its world matrix. (The scalar equivalent of one)  In this case the local vertex coordinates are also global or world coordinates.   If you choose to change this and give the liver some object transform it will no longer be the case that local vert coordinates match their global coordinates.  The docs for `world_to_camera_view` stipulate that the `coord` argument be in world space.  Hence the "_some people you've seen_" using `ob.matrix_world @ v.co` are correctly converting the local vert coord to world.

Comment: @batFINGER I haven't rotated or shifted my liver in any manner however the ` obj.matrix_world` outputs this as following ```Matrix(((1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
(0.0, -1.6292068494294654e-07, -1.0, 0.0),
(0.0, 1.0, -1.6292068494294654e-07, 0.0),
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))```.So wont multiplying this matrix along with my vertices make a difference?

Comment: Identity is `[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], ]` _ie_ all zeros and a principle diagonal of ones.  (consider `1.7e-07`  ==  (`1.7  / 10, 000, 000`) to be zero).  Your matrix is not identity.  Consider using actual bounding box  `[obj.matrix_world @ Vector(b) for b in obj.bound_box]` where `obj` is liver object. To create your coords.

Comment: @batFINGER So if I create the meshgrid from the vertices obtained from `[obj.matrix_world @ Vector(b) for b in obj.bound_box]` then I would not be required to do `cords = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam,obj.matrix_world @ vert)`as already the `verts`are in world space right?So `cords = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, vert)` should work ?

Comment: Yes.  Pretty sure that's the case.